# How to not import types/interfaces/classes with the same name with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, tsconfig, tsc

I used to have a simple filestructure of 5 files in one folder:

- classes.ts
- hello.ts
- types.ts
- functions.ts
- tsconfig.json

tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2015",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "strict": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false
      },
      "files": [
        "classes.ts",
        "hello.ts",
        "functions.ts",
        "types.ts"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
      ]
    }
```

However, as time passes I started to have type/interface/class names collision.
The question is: how do I prevent classes.ts from knowing about a particular type (or all of them) from hello.ts?
It seems like they were implicitly imported which isn't the desired behaviour for me.

I tried separating them into different folders with a different tsconfig.json per folder but then .ts files are not compiled all at once, just folder-by-folder.

Comment: You say "import" and specify module type "commonjs", but are the source files modules? They'd be modules if you use `import`/`export`/`require` within the files, or set `exports` or `module.exports`. (There's a further difference between ES modules and CommonJS modules, but first let's get to whether these are modules or scripts.)

Comment: Yes, those are scripts.

Comment: Have you tried giving things different names? Some people like to prefix interfaces with `I` and types with `T` or even append the entire word to the name (`IFooInterface`, `TBarType`). How big are these files that you already have naming collisions?

Comment: They are not very big, however I want them as simple as possible. Probably what I want/expect is behavior similar to Jupiter Notebooks, where "scripts" (notebooks) can be placed into one folder but do not implicitly interact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript distinguishes between two types of files:

- *modules*, which might be in CommonJS or ES dialects
- *scripts*, which do not use "import", "export", "module.exports", or any other module machinery, and consequently everything defined in a script goes into the global namespace.

As in the ["Modules" Handbook docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html#how-javascript-modules-are-defined), emphasis mine:

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module.
>
> Conversely, **a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope** (and therefore to modules as well).

Despite your use of the term "import types", you clarified in the comments that these are scripts, such that these types are not imported as they would be in modules: Everything defined in the global namespaces is accessible to everything else defined in the global namespace. As in [this Handbook reference example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) advocating for *namespaces*, emphasis mine:

> As we add more validators, we’re going to want to have some kind of organization scheme so that we can keep track of our types and not worry about name collisions with other objects. **Instead of putting lots of different names into the global namespace, let’s wrap up our objects into a namespace.**

That Handbook reference page suggests one solution, which is to use the `namespace` keyword to give potential collisions more specific names; you can then use [*aliases*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases) to reduce the length of the names to type. However, you might also consider using explicit [*modules*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), which were designed with modularity and name collision avoidance in mind.

Comment: Using namespaces is probably the best solution available.
However, it is quite strange that to avoid implicit imports one has to declare an import/export. Maybe there's a way to change that behaviour?

Comment: "Global scope" has existed in JavaScript as long as JavaScript has existed; I think that breaking the "implicit imports" mental model will be helpful in the long run as long as you work with JavaScript. The behavior is not configurable, but the [newer file extensions `mts` and `cts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html#new-file-extensions) can be used to treat your files as modules (and therefore out of the global namespace) regardless of top-level imports and exports.